# Executing a function after all async functions have completed?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

```
this.validate_label_population();
this.validate_title_prefix();
this.validate_title_suffix();
this.executeGitCommentCreation();
```

I have the following functions executing in a constructor. The top 3/4 are async functions:

Example:

```
  async validate_title_prefix() {
    console.log('validate_title_prefix not implemented');
  }
```

I want to execute `this.executeGitCommentCreation();` last after al the previous have ran. What is the best way to do this? Should I throw await in front of the top 3, or use some sort of Promise.all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as opinion-based. There isn't an objective answer. I'd use `Promise.all` so that the first 3 can run concurrently if that's possible, but you could make that work with async/await if you wanted to.

Comment: I'm not asking for an opinion. I literally don't know how to do it.

Comment: Ah my bad. When you mentioned await and Promise.all I thought you knew how to use them and were asking which was better. For my $0.02 Duc Filan's answer is better than await for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this snippet:

```
Promise.all([
    this.validate_label_population(), 
    this.validate_title_prefix(), 
    this.validate_title_suffix()
])
.then(function(values) {
    this.executeGitCommentCreation();
}.bind(this));
```

or you can use arrow function to get the correct context:

```
Promise.all([
    this.validate_label_population(), 
    this.validate_title_prefix(), 
    this.validate_title_suffix()
])
.then(values => {
    this.executeGitCommentCreation();
});
```

or you even can cache the this to the outside context:

```
var _this = this;
Promise.all([
    this.validate_label_population(), 
    this.validate_title_prefix(), 
    this.validate_title_suffix()
])
.then(function(values) {
    _this.executeGitCommentCreation();
});
```

For more information, read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

P/s: Your naming convention is not unified (mixed with camel case and snake case). I recommend using `camelCase` on vars/functions, `PascalCase` on classes, and `ALL_CAPS` on constants.

Comment: Thank you sir. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: How can I bind(this) to this ?

Comment: Great, thanks. I was doing _this = this, but wanted the bind answer. Thanks!

Comment: Do these functions need to be invoked? Based on my tests, they do, but in your example, they aren't

Comment: It depends. If it's a Promise then it's not otherwise, it needs.

Comment: since `executeGitCommentCreation` doesn't seem to take arguments, and if it truly ignores them, you could `Promise.all([....]).then(this.executeGitCommentCreation)` thereby removing the need for binding `this`

Comment: Yes, exactly so.